# header can't pass and get parameters

Tags: php, parameters, header

I used header to pass the parameter, but didn't work

Here is Page 1:

```
session_start();

$_SESSION['favcolor'] = 'green';
$_SESSION['animal']   = 'cat';
$_SESSION['time']     = time();
$problem  = "correct";

header('Location:trynew2.php?problem=$problem');

?>
```

Here is my 2nd page:

```
<?php
session_start();

echo "welcome" ;
$problem = $_GET['problem'];
echo $problem;

$test = $_SESSION['favcolor'];
echo $test;
?>
```

and the result is welcome$problemgreen

Comment: Can you add the first page, please? `echo $problem;` won't print out `$problem`, but since I can't see how you're setting `$_GET['problem'];`, I can't see if there's a problem elsewhere.

Comment: We're going to need the initial page.

Comment: The above code will print value of $problem and in no case it will print $problem itself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using single quotes just echoes out what you put in there, and doesn't process the variables. You need to use double quotes on your header line

```
header("Location:trynew2.php?problem=$problem");
```

Comment: Thank you, it works now. I'm new to php. I wonder when should use double quotes and when should use single quotes?

Comment: It's mostly a personal preference, but if you're going to place a variable in the middle of a string without concatenating it, then use double quotes. This link might help a bit: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Comment: This as well: http://www.trans4mind.com/personal_development/phpTutorial/quotes.htm

Answer (score 0):

```
header('Location:trynew2.php?problem=$problem');
```

That will send you to the next page with a URL of:

```
trynew2.php?problem=$problem
```

Single quotes do not interpolate variables; if you want this to behave as expected, you need to use double quotes:

```
header("Location:trynew2.php?problem=$problem");
```